# Mysql query to fetch immediate records with dates less than and greater than a given datetime

Tags: mysql, sql, jooq

I would like to get records with dates around a given date .I  have a table like this

```
+----+---------------+
| id | event_date    |
+----+---------------+
| 1 | 1470594600000 |
| 2 | 1471804200000 |
| 3 | 1472409000000 |
| 4 | 1473013800000 |
| 5 | 1480271400000 |
| 6 | 1485109800000 |
+----+---------------+
```

If a given time is 1475087400458 which is between dates with id's 4 and 5,
i would like to fetch 3 records nearby the given date which is 1473013800000,1480271400000 and 1485109800000.
I tried ordering the rows using ABS()  finding the difference between the dates and limiting it to 3 but it is returning records with id 2,3,4 .
What is the best way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: They are the closest ones available, if you always want something from before and after you may need to use UNION

Comment: Thanks for the idea :) found it .